# Spring Post: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, spring, rest, post

### I am using spring rest APIs and getting Http 405 error for all the POST methods.

I have following POST method,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GetPlanByBasicContext/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Plan getPlanByBasicContext(@RequestBody BasicPlanContext basicPlanContext) 
{
  return planService.getPlanByBasicContext(basicPlanContext);
}
```

I am using fiddler to post the following request,

POST
http://localhost:8080/now/Plan/GetPlanByBasicContext

```
{ "sourceLocation":"",  
  "destinationLocation":"", 
  "modeOfTransport":"car"
  "budget":"any"
}
```

Same attributes are present in BasicPlanContext on the server, along with getters and setters.

I have tried other solutions mentioned and nothing has worked.

Note: Security is not configured for spring yet.

Comment: please put your murkup too.

Comment: I am using fiddler to make the POST request. Not using HTML yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are posting to a wrong `URL` , you are missing a trailing `slash` in the end of your `URL`, try posting to :  `http:// localhost:8080/now/Plan/GetPlanByBasicContext/`